# Diagnose error 500 from the client side

Tags: html, 500-error, 500

Is there any way to diagnose an Error 500 from the client side?

I'm getting an error 500 on a folder on our server.  It's running PrestaShop and was working fine up until a few minutes ago.  I've asked our hosting company to look into it.

Till they do, is there a way to diagnose from my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out GAThrawn was on the right track.  I renamed our customer 500 error page then shortly after that a 403 started showing up.  I double checked with our hosting company, [Arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/), and something did go array in the permissions on that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Does it just say Error 500, or is there more than that on the error page (if it has triggered one of Internet Explorer's default error pages, then scroll to the bottom of the page and/or click to view more info, or use another web browser)?

Do you have access to your server's log files?

Depending on OS, web server, and language the app was written in it's quite possible that some useful info (that might at least point you in vaguely the right direction) is in one of the log files.

Comment: Here's the error 500
http://pastie.org/601058

Answer (score 0):

Unless your host has some form of debug output on their 500 error message, there is very little to diagnose I am afraid. the 500 message as you know is returned by page generated by the server and theres usually very little to go by in bother headers & content, :(